# Command line tools for checking if a VPN is leaking on a headless device

Tags: network, vpn, data-leakage

I have a headless device that is connected to a router with a VPN connection. Not al the devices connected to the router go through the VPN connection, since I have set rules on the router to tell it which devices want to be routed to the VPN. Specifically this device and a guest network are the only ones that are routed through the VPN.

My question is, how can I test that everything is correctly configured and there isn't VPN leaks on the headless device? I've already tested the connection on the guest network with this web (http://www.doileak.com) but I really don't know how to proceed on the headless device.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have any access to the headless device? ssh, rdp, teamviewer. You can use wireshark and check the packets.

Comment: @pioupiou yeah I have ssh access, it's a sort of a raspberry pi. Actually is a cubox-i with a dietpi linux installed on it.